# How to enable print action when using "View Invoice" button in Prestashop 1.6 Admin dashboard

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Currently I am creating a new project based on Prestashop 1.6. There are some features where I'd like to make some changes.

When logging in as an administrator, the "orders" will show all the customer orders. There are three buttons existing on the dashboard, Print Order, View Invoice, View delivery slip, they will generate PDF files.

Originally the Print order button can open up a new window for users to print the PDF, while the rest two buttons can't. They will just directly download the PDF.

I am just wondering if there is any way that can make the action into popping up a new window for printing. Anyone experienced in Prestrashop can help? I'll be so much thankful.

Here is what it looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

the only solution is to create a new controller that generate the requested pdf and add the print() javascript in it. In this case the pdf is loaded and the print dialog is opened automatically. And you call the new controller in the view.tpl by creating yours in

**/override/controllers/admin/templates/orders/helpers/view.tpl**

Here is a sample that call **AdminPrintDeliveryslip** controller :

```
<a class="btn btn-default"  href="javascript:void(0)">
    <span onclick="w=window.open('{$link->getAdminLink('AdminPrintDeliveryslip')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}&amp;id_order={$order->id|intval}', 'popupWindow', 'width=850,height=700,scrollbars=yes');">
        <i class="icon-print"></i>
        {l s='Print delivery slip'}
     </span>
</a>
```

I don't post the controller code here, is too big :-(

Hope this help,

John